# Necessary and sufficient condition for a ring homomorphisms property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question states: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $A,B\subseteq R$ be two ideals, find a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathrm{Hom}(R/A,R/B)=0$.

Since $\mathrm{Hom}(R/A,R/B)\cong(B:A)/B$, so I guess one such condition is $(B:A)=B$.

Update (see comments below):

Before I found the reference of that isomorphism, the original guess ($A+B=(1)=R$) serves a sufficient condition since $A+B=R\rightarrow(B:A)=B$.

Comment: Can you prove that that condition works?

Comment: @user26857, You mean $(I:J)$?

Comment: $\hom$ in which category? (This should always be indicated.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg in $A$-module category

Comment: @user26857 sorry my problem set is mixed with both A/B I/J notation, now it's fixed.